# How can I make an hover effect on these text?

Tags: html, css

> If I hover over the image div, the text section will become from the
> bottom... [I want something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfnCf.png).
>
> I have added my HTML and CSS code below
> ================================================

```css
.photo-album .common .details {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(200%);
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.photo-album .common .photo::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00000086;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: .3s ease-in;
  z-index: 8;
}

.photo-album .common .photo:hover.photo::after {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.photo-album .common .photo:hover.details {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<section class="photo-album">
    <div class="common">
      <div class="photo">
        <div class="border-top border"></div>
        <div class="border-right border"></div>
        <div class="border-bottom border"></div>
        <div class="border-left border"></div>
        <img src="./images/ayon.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <h1>Ayon Jodder</h1>
        <p>Student of Programming Hero</p>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: where is `.photo-album` in your html? this `.photo-album .common .photo:hover.photo::after` doesn't match anything inyour code. HAve you make some research on google?

Comment: Please check now. that .photo-album is the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You have not used photo-album in your html,Try this code for your reference

```html
<style>
.hovertext {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.hovertext:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 110%;
}

.hovertext:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<section class="class="hovertext" data-hover="text">
    <div >
      <div>
        <div class="border-top border"></div>
        <div class="border-right border"></div>
        <div class="border-bottom border"></div>
        <div class="border-left border"></div>
        <img src="./images/ayon.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="hovertext"data-hover="text">
        <h1>Ayon Jodder</h1>
        <p>Student of Programming Hero</p>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That did not work ;(